# Getting Error while adding a new Workflow in my document Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, office-365, lookup-column

I already have 6 workflows running in one of my Document Library. If I am adding a new Workflow, it is throwing error as - "The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold enforced by the administrator".

I have gone through many articles on this. All suggested the default threshold is 8 lookup. [Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba240e0c-2435-4215-bb70-41b374634172/the-query-cannot-be-completed-because-the-number-of-lookup-columns-it-contains-exceeds-the-lookup?forum=sharepointadminprevious) ... then why I am getting this on adding 7th WF. I don not have any other lookup field in Doc library

I am working on Sharepoint Online. Is there any way to modify these default limits? Or If someone can explain about my issue? TIA

Comment: You have to consider `Created By` and `Modified By` also as lookups.

Comment: aah.. thats right! I didn't thought through this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to consider the `Created By` and `Modified By` columns also as lookup columns. Then the total will be 8 in your case and reaches maximum limit.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you are hitting the **list view** threshold, an actual SharePoint list can hold a lot of columns.

But it is weird that you hit limit at 8 columns, as Microsoft states that 12 is the default in Office 365. Sounds like they either lowered it, or you might want to give them a call

Do you really need to show all of your SharePoint workflow status columns in the same view/default view? As long as you don't have more than 8 lookup columns in your default view, you will be fine.

Comment: Even if I hide all WF status from the list view, The issue still persist

Comment: Ah, might be an O365 limit. Guess it is to resource expensive.